# Using icons for app from internet for android app

Tags: android

I am wondering what are the legal ramifications of using an icon from the internet in my app. I am not much of an artist but there are gazillions of icons on the web. I was going to use one and tweak it a bit and use it for my android app. Is this legal to do?

Thanks.

Comment: that depends on the image distribution rights. Each image has it's own rights. You have to check for specific image.

Comment: Google image search has a feature to filter images based on what licence they're published under.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because legal questions are not programming.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish you can use your icons from drawable folder by creating vector icons giving it your own colors and styles[image]